# List and array size difference

Tags: vb.net

I was under the impression that List(Of T) is a utility wrapper around a basic array but today while testing, i found that lists are up to twice the size in memory as arrays are. This is relevant to me since with my current implementation using lists, the database is some 1.5gb which is riding a bit too close to the 32bit limit for my taste since this doesn't include rest of the program. If I could cut that in half, that would be awesome.

I use lists for their conventient resizing ability but I figured I could maybe build my own wrapper class around arrays to achieve the same thing at lower memory usage. So what I did for testing was this:

```
Public Class funnylist
    Private arrlist As New List(Of Long())
    Private rcount As Integer = 0
    Private incsize As Integer = 1000
    Private lastArr As Integer = -1
    Private maxCount As Integer = 0
    Private lastsub As Integer = -incsize
    Public Sub add(n As Long)
        If rcount = maxCount Then
            arrlist.Add(New Long(incsize) {})
            lastArr += 1
            lastsub += incsize
            maxCount += incsize
        End If

        arrlist(lastArr)(rcount - lastsub) = n

        rcount += 1
    End Sub
End Class
```

could use some polishing obviously but as a proof of concept it works, the memory footprint for the same amount of items is half that of a list(of Long). Problem is though, i populated both list and funnylist with 10 million counts of the number 5 and timed it. List is exactly twice as fast at doing that. So I'm wondering whats going on under the hood of a List exactly? Why is it bigger and why is it faster? Any tips on improving my funnylist?

Comment: You wouldn't want the list to always have a capacity of exactly its number of elements.  The way a list grows is strategic. It does not have to perform an allocation every time you want to add an element. In your case it probably expanded greatly due to the sheer amount of elements you are storing.  If you know that you need a certain size then initialize your list to that capacity.  Of course, if you need a static size, you could also just use an array...

Comment: That a list or array can require double the amount of memory is meaningless.  It is *virtual memory*, just a number to the processor.  You don't start using *real* memory until you access it.  Which of course never happens with the top end.  When you write programs that consume all available address space then you write bad code.  Any program that reads a jiggabyte of data from a dbase and then processes it can be rewritten to process a single row at a time, requiring only kilobytes.  You can continue to write bad code by allowing it to run in 64-bit mode, very hard to run out of address space

Comment: I don't think its virtual, i compiled in 64 bit and the moment the memory use reached around 15gb (i have 16gb physical in total) it crashed with out of memory exception.

PS! the reason i don't actually want to compile it in 64bit is because that also makes the whole thing run a significant amount slower (like 30% by my measure)

I get what you're saying about loading up all the data in one shot but there is going to be a crapton of randomly distributed processing and going to the disk each time would be rather counterproductive.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be interested to see how the performance would compare if you were to exclusively use a Long array in your wrapper rather than a List(Of Long) and dynamically resize it as you add new numbers. Give this a try. Pass a Long to the constructor to initialise the wrapper's internal array then use the Add method to add further numbers. You can retrieve the current array from the MyArray property.

```
Public Class FunnyList

    Private _myArray As Long()

    Public Sub New(n As Long)
        _myArray = New Long() {n}
    End Sub

    Public Sub Add(n As Long)
       Dim iUBound As Integer = _myArray.GetUpperBound(0) 
       ReDim Preserve _myArray(iUBound + 1)
       _myArray(iUBound + 1) = n
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property MyArray() As Long()
        Get
            Return _myArray
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Comment: Well i tried it, redimming is extremely slow in comparison (like thousands of times slower). I suspect it uses a similar mechanic as Array.Resize which i used initially and was also too slow. Also it makes the memory use up and down, i think its just creating a new array and fully copying the old one over every single time.